# Read (unnamed) argument in console line

Tags: c#, command-line

As ConsoleFx seems to be progressing too slow (bummer, it had much potential) and showing too many breaking changes every build, I decided to switch to Mono.Options for my commandline parsing needs.

My OptionSet is built in the following method

```
private static OptionSet BuildOptionSet()
{
    OptionSet optionSet = new OptionSet()
        .Add("?|help|h", "Prints out the options", option => help = option != null)
        .Add("w|wait", "Waits for any key after finished processing", option => wait)
    return optionSet;
}
```

All tutorials I find, deal with options and how to capture them, but arguments are never mentioned.

The following call for example

```
   c:\>test.exe brandCode1 brandCode2 /w
```

Should put wait on true and give me two arguments with values brandCode1 and brandCode2.
How can I capture them in a clean way from the args[] ?

Is this not possible with Mono.Options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell from reading the docs, you need to call `OptionSet`'s [`parse`](http://www.ndesk.org/doc/ndesk-options/NDesk.Options/OptionSet.html#M:NDesk.Options.OptionSet.Parse(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.String%7D)) method at some point.  When you do, it processes your actions and returns "A `List<string>` containing all unhandled arguments."

Unfortunately, you also need to pass it the main method's argument to get this to work.

```
List<string> extra = optionSet.Parse(args);
```

Edit: In case my link (still) isn't working, parse should link to http://www.ndesk.org/doc/ndesk-options/NDesk.Options/OptionSet.html#M:NDesk.Options.OptionSet.Parse%28System.String,NDesk.Options.OptionContext%29

Comment: This is true. I think you can set a handler as well for unhandled options, but I've never tried that myself.

Comment: I'll be honest, I went solely from the docs on this one, as I've not used Mono Options, and when I saw that it returned the unprocessed options when you ran parse, I just assumed that was the only way to do it.

Comment: Hehe, I have, in MS .NET even ;)

Comment: This seems to work indeed. Sadly this leaves testing for the number of arguments etc to the client library. Well, no biggy.

Comment: Also, if you use WriteOptionDescriptions(), you will need to add the description of the unnamed parameters on top of that. Even worse, the unrecognized options list will contain everything you didn't explicitely add to the option set. So, in your example, if you say "test.exe brandCode1 /x /w", you will get both brandCode1 and /x as unrecognized options :(